# What is Lukas Rotter's secret?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The former user [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14478/lukas-rotter) <strike>has</strike> had<sup>1</sup> an intriguing profile picture:

[image: Lukas Rotter]

This looks like it's some kind of encrypted message! And just to confirm my suspicions, on his profile he says:

> By the way, my profile picture is also a little puzzle. You'll get +0 reputation if you solve it!

Now I'm a generous soul, so I'm going to award you at least +25 reputation if you solve it, and I'm sure you'll get more +10's from others too! How's that for a deal?

### **What is the solution of the puzzle in Lukas Rotter's profile picture?**

<sub>**Note 1:** That user has now deleted their account; however, this puzzle is still self-contained and valid.</sub>

<sub>**Note 2:** I do not know the solution myself. Obviously Lukas does, so you'll have to ask him for any hints or clues.</sub>

<sub>**Note 3**: this [isn't the first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15085/what-is-leoll2-trying-to-tell-us) puzzle I've done like this, by the way ;-)</sub>

Comment: What if it's a troll question and there is no solution

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Then I guess Lukas will owe me a bunch of rep for all the downvotes I'll get :-P

Comment: [I'll sue you for infringing my copyright](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dwo19Y4tw0l8&ved=0ahUKEwiOuLOx_fvOAhUBKMAKHVu0DiAQtwIIGzAA&usg=AFQjCNGaWtsqaDBSEoSPFCjQzivLy9AdmA&sig2=3uE7WL6hkWgs2KzFcgjoPw) :P

Comment: @Lukas It's not plagiarism - I've cited my source! :-P

Comment: @LukasRotter You just uncovered a hidden gem we (read: I) searched for!

Comment: @randal'thor 1) Sticking your tongue out is not funny by itself 2) Lukas intended to write this as a joke 3) Copyright infringement is not always plagiarism; you can cite the source, but the author has denied quoting from the source because of copyright reasons.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος 2) Yes, I already knew Lukas was making a joke (given his `:P`). 3) I was also making a joke (hence my `:-P`). 1) See above.

Comment: A big hint is the use of PNG. With JPEG this (probably) wouldn't work.

Comment: Note: user14478's account has been deleted.

Comment: [hey look Lucas Rotter made new account](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714/lukas-rotter)...or did he?

Comment: @EKons *Vsauce intensifies*

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's

> Hexadeximal encoded ASCII (translated onto RGB color space) for **LukasRotter**

Because

> The colors are, from left to right #4C756B, #617352, #6F7474 and we add 65 and 72 as per the text, giving the full text: 
> `4C 75 6B 61 73 52 6F 74 74 65 72` = `LukasRotter`

---

To elaborate, [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a standardized representation of text which assigns a numeric value to 128 different characters.

The [RGB color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space) is an [additive color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color) where we mix red, green, and blue in different proportions (in this case, as fractions of 255) to make any color we desire. These mixtures are commonly written in the form `#RRGGBB` where `RR` is the base-16 quantity of red, `GG` green, and `BB` blue. I used a color picker browser extension on the image to extract the hexadecimal representations of the colors.

Comment: Guess I need to watch NumberPhile more...

Comment: @Έρικ I had not seen the video from which Lukas got the idea, I've just seen this trick a lot. :P

Comment: [Really? Didn't you see it?](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dwo19Y4tw0l8&ved=0ahUKEwiOuLOx_fvOAhUBKMAKHVu0DiAQtwIIGzAA&usg=AFQjCNGaWtsqaDBSEoSPFCjQzivLy9AdmA&sig2=3uE7WL6hkWgs2KzFcgjoPw)

Comment: @Έρικ Well I have _now_, but I'm saying it didn't inform my answer.

Comment: Oh, because I saw it, and I was actually convinced you had seen it before.