# What is JonMarkPerry trying to tell us?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Following in the footsteps of [MOehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48338/what-is-moehm-trying-to-tell-us), [leoll2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15085/what-is-leoll2-trying-to-tell-us) and the formerly known [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42158/what-is-lukas-rotters-secret?noredirect=1&lq=1) (who has deleted his account D:), we have a new name to add: [JonMarkPerry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11497/jonmark-perry)!

In his profile we find an interesting image:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

*(For colourblind: From left to right:*

*Yellow Red Orange Blue*
*Purple Dark Blue Red Green*
*Pink Blue Yellow Purple*
*Green Dark Blue Orange Pink)*

Followed by the line

> The diagonals are all **45°**, and therefore +/-/0 1.

Observations:

- There are two of each colour
- 8 colours and the 0 1 seems to suggest binary
- For two inputs of each colour could be a logic gate
- Almost seems to be colours of the rainbow

So, you know the drill:

## What is JonMarkPerry trying to tell us?

(Also note his profile pic has changed to a pic of Hank Williams III which may or may not be related)

Will add bounty in about a week if not solved.

Comment: Aaah, interestinge...

Comment: Also, let's not forget that shade of grey in background, and the black lines :0

Comment: Lukas Rotter no longer exists.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I know he changed his name to Display Name. Or are you saying he deleted his account?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil His account was deleted.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος oh no! Thats a shame. Thanks for letting me know I'll add it in the question

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil [Deletion proof.](/users/14478)

Comment: all the colours are/were primitive MS Paint colours, and 45degree lines are a lot quicker to render than say 30degree ones, if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea if this is a coincidence, and it probably is buuut...

I took the distances of each cell to its partner. this was always greater than two. I subtracted two from each of these values, then joined them to make a ternary number:
1011100221112012. this is 16670426. we can convert this into letters by making letters as large as possible unless it is not possible to be a letter (66 is no letter). this becomes pfgdz. putting this into imgur gets this
(for some reason it doesn't like the format)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e85xq.jpg

Probably a coincidence because there was no communication of lower and uppercase letters. but if it isn't this might help.

---

Also I looked through some of the other capitalisations and I do not recommend it. what matters is probably just that the full caps didn't have anything

Comment: Well thats a nice idea, but probably was a coincidence...

Comment: Aah, this is fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

The hex codes of colors are:

FFF200 ED1C24 FFC20E 00B7EF
6F3198 4D6DF3 ED1C24 A8E61D
FFA3B1 00B7EF FFF200 6F3198
A8E61D 4D6DF3 FFC20E FFA3B1

Yellow : FFF200,
Red : ED1C24,
Orange : FFC20E,
Blue : 00B7EF,
Purple : 6F3198,
Dark-Blue : 4D6DF3,
Green : A8E61D,
Pink : FFA3B1,

(#DCDCDC) the shade of grey in the background.

---

Trying to analyse this...