# What is MOehm trying to tell us?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[MOehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm) has an interesting (updated) profile picture:

[image]

It is a lower case and italic 'm' (supposedly for 'M'Oehm) surrounded by what appears to be braille.

The braille says (in UEB, may mean different in other languages): (* used to indicate braille that has no apparent meaning)

> ```
> ka;ak*k l*,*
> ```
>
> ```
> a,*b,la* ,;ak
> ```

Some of the unknown symbols could be rotated or flipped symbols. However the rest doesn't make sense.

## What is MOehm trying to tell us?

Note: I don't know the answer. If it turns out rude or inappropriate (Which I doubt) don't blame me. Puzzles like this [have been done before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15085/what-is-leoll2-trying-to-tell-us), and are therefore on-topic.

Comment: Oh! I finally get my 15 minutes of fame!

Comment: @MOehm Right, so now that you are here, and you aren't allowed to answer, are there really anything significant in them or will we bang our heads in a wall?

Comment: @MOehm also I am assuming this is alright by you?

Comment: Yes, that's alright with me, no sweat. My ego even enjoys it! `:)`

Comment: Gosh darn it, you beat me to it! (+1)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you

> [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) / [OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OR_gate) (doesn't matter since the input is never `11`) each braille code with the one on the opposite side of it.

you get

> `MISFORMARTIN`,

which means

> <del>a wordplay of `MISFORMATTING` (his first name is Martin)</del>.
> `M IS FOR MARTIN` (Thanks to [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) for enlightening me).

Giving the real name

> Martin Oehm

Comment: Misformatin' lol

Answer (score 7):

I have yet to post a puzzle, but thanks to Beastly Gerbil I can write one of these [wrap-up posts](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/sharing-and-rewarding-what-went-into-making-a-good-puzzle), if only to show an alternative way to decode the message.

> Rotter's Slave has solved and explained the code. It can be described as an OR, but I had intended something simpler. You can see that from the original Braille sentence, alternating right and left columns were moved to the bottom row, leaving gaps of two empty columns in both rows:
>
>  [image: Close-up of Braille pattern]
>
>  The idea was to break up the Braille pattern and to allow for easy image manipulation. For example, you can overlay the two patterns in MS Paint if you make the white background transparent. The code was not meant to be difficult to crack. I think the Braille theme is quite obvious.
>
>  The message itself was inspired by 11 Across of [this crossword puzzle](https://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/quiptic/882). I don't have a life motto or anything like that, so I thought I'd explain a detail of the rather businesslike handle I chose when I signed up for Stack Overflow. I liked the "M is for ..." device and it seems I could mislead Rotter's Slave, although not for long.
>
>  Unfortunalely, I changed my icon in a week that saw a deluge of Braille puzzles. And I had hoped that the two rows of Braille would make a nice decorative frieze for the icon, but it looks rather bland at small sizes. Oh, well!