# Thanks for all your help

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

This is a thank you to all those who've either welcomed me to Puzzling or have assisted me in learning new puzzles and giving me tons of feedback. I appreciate all of it. (*Sorry* not everyone I've encountered is in here).

**Disclaimer:** They are in no particular order, I'm not thanking anyone more than someone else.

**V.**

> (49/7) | #/# | I ate | V | 4! - 4 | 2^8 / 32

**I.**

> Gorilla Meme
>  Sky holder
>  Very much
>
> Flattened tree
>  E.g. basil
>  Wicked

**E.**

> `- . -.-. .... .. -.. .. --- -`

**D.**

*Twister*

> appreciated
>  certain
>  knowledgeable
>  uptempo
>   gregarious
>  extra
>  nondescript
>  amici
>  talented

**O.**

> biɘT ↄokɘ TYqiꙅT

**S.**

> (Passphrase is from extending their user*name*) 
> `Pei aqyrssxzrutv Fiaz all Uüaohvg`

**U.**

> Australian golfer started solving puzzles before 30th century. (6)

Comment: Well I see an anagram of a certain moderator in there straight away

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil They can't all be super intricate now can they... ;_;

Comment: Yeah, 'i' is missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going down: (Italic text is from OP for reasoning behind clues)

V from Sid:

> Gives '7 1 18 5 20 8' which is A1Z26 for **[GARETH](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan)** - *Gareth is good at math so he got a number based clue.*

I (idea from Sconibulus):

> Is indeed I: **[BEASTLY GERBIL](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil)** - HARAM**BE** ATL**AS** MOS**TLY** (or greatly) PA**GE** HE**RB** EV**IL** - *Reference to an animal as Gerbil thinks he's an actual rodent.*

E:

> **[TECHIDIOT](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30887/techidiot)** - Morse code - *I often misread their name with DOT not DIOT so it made me think of morse code.*

D from Silenus:

> **[ANKOGANIT](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)** - taking first and last letters alternatively - *Their image has twisting words so it made me think of this clue.*

O from Sid:

> 'Diet Coke Typist' = **[RUBIO](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio)** - Each letter reversed - *Just a reference to the diet coke in his image.*

S from Deusovi:

> **[MOEHM](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm)** - The keyword of 'MARTIN' ([his full first name](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48338/what-is-moehm-trying-to-tell-us) gives 'der hilfsbereite mann aus münchen' or 'The helpful man from Munich' - *He's from Germany so I incorporated the language.*

U:

> **[Sp3000](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/445/sp3000)** - Cryptic clue, he is australian, big on code golf and he 'starts **s**olving **p**uzzles' before 3000 (30th century) - *Reference to his high rep on puzzle golf.*

Overall:

> **[DEUSOVI](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi)** - anagramming the letters outside the boxes - *His name is an anagram so why not mix it up again.*

Comment: @n_palum hope I'm in here ;)

Comment: Don't you worry ;)

Comment: I was too easy :-)

Comment: @Techidiot I think the reason I missed the second 'i' initially was because I thought, oh 'dot'! I'll do morse code because that has dots!

Answer (score 3):

**COMPLETE ANSWER:**

The first one:

> 7 18 5 20 8 (The #/# is probably 1) which gives: [Gareth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan)

I is:(Thanks to Sconibulus)

> [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil). (HaramBE, atlAS, MosTLY, PaGE, heRB, evIL)

O is:

> Diet Coke Typist- Which is [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio)

E is:

> Morse code which decoded gives [Techidiot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30887/techidiot)

U is:

> [Sp3000](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/445/sp3000) (Def- Aus Golfer. Starting letters of Solving puzzles

Beastly Gerbil has astutely observed that:

> The letters outside the boxes anagram to [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi)

S is:(Thanks to Deusovi)

> A vigenere cipher with key MARTIN which decodes to "der hilfsbereite mann aus münchen" which translates to "The helpful Man from Munich" - [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm)

D is:

> [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit). (Taking the first and last letters in an alternating manner)

Comment: The #/# is intended to be 1 yes, you're missing the / in your answer

Comment: I really wouldn't bother crediting me with 'DEUSOVI' :P

Comment: S is Vigenere with keyword MARTIN (Oehm), decoding to "der hilfsbereite mann aus münchen" which means "The helpful man from Munich" according to Google Translate